# EntityFramework generating poor tsql (linqpad generates much better)

Tags: c#, linq, wcf, entity-framework, odata

I have a database structure as below

Family(1) ----- (*) FamilyPersons *-----(1)Person(1)------(*) Expenses (1) -----(0..1)GroceriesDetails

Let me explain that relation, Family can have one or more than one person , we have a mapping table FamilyPersons between Family and Persons.  Now each person can enter his expenses which go into Expenses Table. Expense Table has a column ExpenseType (groceries, entertainemnet etc)
and details of each of these expenses goes into their own Tables, so we have a GroceriesDetails table (similarly we have other tables), so we have 1 to 0..1 relation between Expense and Groceries.

Now I am writing a query to get Complete GroceriesDetails for a family

```
GroceriesDetails.Where (g => g.Expenses.Person.FamilyPersons.Any(fp => 
fp.FamilyId == 1) && g.Expenses.ExpenseType == "GC" )
```

For this the sql generated by EF is

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Amount] AS [Amount]
FROM  [dbo].[GroceriesDetails] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id1]
    FROM  [dbo].[Expenses] AS [Extent2]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[GroceriesDetails] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Extent3].[Id]
    WHERE N'GC' = [Extent2].[ExpenseType] ) AS [Filter1] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Filter1].[Id1]
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM   [dbo].[Expenses] AS [Extent4]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[GroceriesDetails] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent4].[Id] = [Extent5].[Id]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[FamilyPerson] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent4].[PersonId] = [Extent6].[PersonId]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent5].[Id]) AND (1 = [Extent6].[FamilyId])
)
```

In this query there is a full table join between Expenses and GroceriesDetails tables which is causing performance issues.

Whereas Linqpad generates a much better SQL

```
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[Amount]
FROM [GroceriesDetails] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [Expenses] AS [t1] ON [t1].[Id] = [t0].[Id]
WHERE (EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [Expenses] AS [t2]
    INNER JOIN [Person] AS [t3] ON [t3].[Id] = [t2].[PersonId]
    CROSS JOIN [FamilyPerson] AS [t4]
    WHERE ([t4].[FamilyId] = @p0) AND ([t2].[Id] = [t0].[Id]) AND ([t4].[PersonId] = 
[t3].[Id])
    )) AND ([t1].[ExpenseType] = @p1)
```

Please note that we are using WCF data services so this query is written against a WCF data service reference, so I can't traverse from top (family) to bottom (Groceries) as OData allows only one level of select.

Any help on optimizing this code is appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK LinqPad does not generate any queries itself, it just makes EF to do so anyway. Are you sure you use the same EF while running the query in LinqPad and in your app? And are you sure that the query is exactly the same and your app does not do anything with it (add more ctiteria, etc)?

Comment: @AlexeyRaga In LinqPad I use Linq 2 Sql for ORM and in my application it is Entity-Framework, and yes it is the same query in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

From the comments I learned that LinqPad uses Linq2SQL while the app uses EF, and that explains the difference.

The thing is that you have zero control on how EF generates SQL.
The only thing you can do is to rewrite your LINQ query to make it "closer" to desired SQL.

For example, instead of

```
GroceriesDetails.Where (g => g.Expenses.Person.FamilyPersons.Any(fp => fp.FamilyId == 1)
                             && g.Expenses.ExpenseType == "GC" )
```

you can try to write something like (pseudocode):

```
from g in GrosseriesDetails
join e in Expenses on g.Id = e.GrosseryId
join p in Persons on p.Id = e.PersonId
join f in FamilyPersons on f.PersonId = p.Id
where f.FamilyId == 1 && e.ExpenseType == "GC"
```

It almost always helps as it tells an ORM a straightforward way to transform it into SQL. The idea is that the expression tree in the "original" case is more complex compare to the proposed scenario, and by simplifying the expression tree we make translator's job easier and more straightforward.

But besides manipulating the LINQ there is no control over how it generates SQL from the expression tree.

Comment: I use WCF dataservices which don't allow joins.